Evaluating $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\sin(\sin(x))e^{\cos(x)}}{x^2}dx$
Immediately, I notice that the integrand is the imaginary part of $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)e^{e^{iz}}}{z^2}$, which led me to think of contour integration.
Let $$I_0=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx, I_1=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}f(z)dz, I_2=\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{C_r}f(z)dz$$ where $C_R$ and $C_r$ are semicircular contours in the top half of the complex plane going clockwise with radii $R$ and $r$ respectively. Then, the goal integral $I=\frac1{2}\Im(I_0)$ and (ignoring some details) $I_0+I_2-I_1=0$ i.e $I_0=I_1-I_2$. Now,
$$\begin{aligned}
I_1&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{C_R}\frac{\sin(z)e^{e^{iz}}}{z^2}dz\\
&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac{i}{R}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(Re^{i\theta})e^{e^{iRe^{i\theta}}}}{e^{i\theta}}d\theta\ (z=Re^{i\theta})\\
&=\lim_{R\to\infty}\frac1{2R}\int_0^\pi\frac{\left(t-\frac1{t}\right)e^t}{e^{i\theta}}d\theta, t=e^{iRe^{i\theta}}\end{aligned}$$ Now, $
t=e^{-R\sin\theta+iR\cos\theta}$, so $|t|\to 0$ as $R\to\infty$. (As $\sin\theta>0$ for $\theta\in (0,\pi)$) However, this doesn't tell use anything useful because of the $1/t$ term. This is as far as I got for the value of $I_1$.
Similarly, $$\begin{aligned}I_2=\frac1{2r}\int_0^\pi\frac{\left(t-\frac1{t}\right)e^t}{e^{i\theta}}d\theta, t=e^{ire^{i\theta}}\end{aligned}$$Now, $t=1+ire^{i\theta}+O(r^2)$ near $r=0$, giving $1/t=1-ire^{i\theta}+O(r^2)$ and $t-1/t=2ire^{i\theta}+O(r^2)$. Also, $e^t=e\cdot e^{t-1}=e(1+O(t-1))=e+O(r)$. Then, $$I_2=i\int_0^\pi (e+O(r))d\theta\to ie\pi$$ If I could calculate the value of $I_1$ I'd be done. Any help would be appreciated!

Using Mathematica: $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\sin(\sin(x))e^{\cos(x)}}{x^2}dx=\frac{e \pi }{2}-\frac{\pi }{2}$$

@MariuszIwaniuk yes, which would mean $I_1$ would have to be equal to $i(2e-1)\pi$..

The modulus of $f$ is unbounded which is the problem. Letting $z=x+iy$ where $y>0$ to restrict ourselves to the upper half plane where $C_R$ is in, we get $\left|\frac{\sin\left(z\right)\exp\left(e^{iz}\right)}{z^{2}}\right|\ge\frac{e^{2y}-1}{2e^{y}\left(\left|x\right|^{2}+2\left|x\right|y+y^{2}\right)}\exp\left(\frac{\cos x}{e^{y}}\right)$. When $y \to \infty$, the lower bound approaches $\infty$ implying that $|f(z)|$ also goes to $\infty$.

$I_{2}$ is going to $- i e \pi $ since $C_{r}$ is clockwise oriented, and $$ \begin{align} I_{1} &= \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_{R}}\frac{\sin (z)}{z^{2}} , \mathrm dz + \lim_{R \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{C_{R}}\frac{\sin(z)}{z^{2}} \frac{e^{inz}}{n!} , \mathrm dz \ &= \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_{R}}\frac{\sin (z)}{z^{2}} , \mathrm dz +0 \end{align}$$
because $\sin(z) e^{inz}$ is bounded in the upper half-plane for $n \ge 1$.

We can then deduce that $ \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{C_{R}}\frac{\sin (z)}{z^{2}} , \mathrm dz = - i \pi$ from the fact that  $\operatorname{PV} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x)}{x^{2}} , \mathrm dx = 0. $

@RandomVariable how does $sin(z)e^{inz}$ being bounded prove that the integral goes to 0 for $n\ge 1$? Are we using Jordan's Lemma here? And how does $PV\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^2}dx =0$ prove that the integral goes to $-i\pi$ on $C_R$?

\begin{align}
& \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x\sin(\sin x)e^{\cos x}}{x^2}dx\\
 = & \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^2} \ \Im {e}^{e^{ix}} dx = \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x^2}  \Im \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(e^{ix})^k}{k!} \ dx\\
= &\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \sin(kx)}{x^2}\ dx
= \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k!} =  \frac{\pi}{2}  \left(e- 1\right)
\end{align}
where
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x\sin kx }{x^2}\;dx
= \int_0^{\infty}\int_{k-1}^{k+1}\frac{\sin xy}{2x}dy\;dx=\int_{k-1}^{k+1}\frac{\pi}{4}dy=\frac\pi2
$$

Nice! Taking the imaginary part operator back inside the summation is a nice technique. I was looking for ways to solve this integral using contour integration though, as it was part of a contour integration worksheet..
